# Docker Image-pip3 Not Found

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to build a Docker image on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL for Windows 10 and keep running into the following error when Docker gets to the step to run pip3 install:

```
/bin/sh: 1: pip3: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY bots/art_print.py /bots/
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /bots
CMD ["python3", "art-print-bot"]
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled pip3 and verified that it is there with $ which pip3

```
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Any ideas as to why the Docker build is not recognizing pip3?

Comment: Are you running that `which` command inside the built image, or from your host?  They have separate filesystems and a shell from one context can't access commands or files in the other.  You might build your image `FROM python:3` instead of a bare Ubuntu image.

Comment: I built the image FROM python:3 and removed logging from requirements.txt as it was throwing an error due to logging already built into python and was able to successfully build the image. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have an issue with your PATH environment variable. Try changing the pip RUN line to:

```
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```